# Is a passive analog "summer" fine, if the output voltage is guaranteed to be lower than the input voltage?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, signal-processing, crosstalk

Suppose that the voltage sources only goes to the analog summer described after. The voltage sources have enough negative DC bias to put voltages to be negative. Since negative plus negative is negative, this satisfies the condition that output sum voltage is lower than input voltage.

In such a case, would a passive analog summer be OK? If not, what would still be the reason to go for an active analog summer?

Comment: Still searching for the passive adder circuit? There are no such easy way. Most of this things are really expensive and big. Look for magnetic amplifier, those things were used some 50 yrs ago in high power electrics.

Comment: I remembered that while was university student we did operate an amplidyne, a gift from Queen Elizabeth in fifties. That was a really an operational amplifier made from brushes, motors,...really big stuff like a car.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an averager not a summer. For instance, with equal series resistors you might have 1V and 2V signals feeding thru individual resistors. 1V and 2V are split by an equal resistance potential divider and hence the output at the junction is precisely 1.5 volts and not 3V as a real summer would achieve.

So if you want to sum signals, use an op-amp summer circuit.